# Where can I set a UINavigationControllers supportedOrientations?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

I am using iOS 6.0 beta and my rotations do not work anymore.

Where can I set a UINavigationControllers supportedOrientations?

According to this http://news.yahoo.com/apple-ios-6-beta-3-changes-182849903.html
a UINavigation Controller does not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate.

I am not using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: anymore as it is deprecated.
Instead I am using supportedInterfaceOrientations: and shouldAutoRotate: and they are working fine until I place a ViewController into a NavigationController (as a Child).
From then on the orientations specified in the ViewController do not work anymore.
It seems it is using the orientations set by the navigation controller (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown)

How can I set the InterfaceOrientations for the NavigationController so that my ViewControllers are locked to Portrait-Orientation?

Do I have to subclass UINavigationController and set the InterfaceOrientations there? Isn't it bad practise to subclass UINavigationController still in iOS 6.0?

Thanks for you help heaps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

If you want it to consult it's children again you can add a category to UINavigationController

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use categories to override the methods of a class, especially one that is built into the operating system. Create a subclass instead.

Comment: I would agree with that... in the end it depends on your situation. This is certainly intended to be a quick compatibility fix for a large project.

Comment: Why is this a bad idea? It's the only one that has worked for me so far and it was simple to set up. I put it in my UITabBarController and viola, I can control the rotations of all my views.

Comment: The reason why overriding those methods in a category is a bad/poor idea is because you'd be bypassing anything that UINavigationController is doing within those methods, and passing their implementation to your own class. By overriding you'll never be able to access the original implementation done by the UINavigationController. By subclassing you are able to call [super someMethod]. You can't do that in a category.

Comment: `[self.viewControllers lastObject]` is just `self.topViewController`

Answer (score 4):

Subclass UINavigationController

//OnlyPortraitNavigationController.h

```
@interface OnlyPortraitNavigationController : UINavigationController
```

//OnlyPortraitNavigationController.m

```
@implementation OnlyPortraitNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; //for locked only Portrait
}
```

present new subclass navigationController with your portrait ViewController

```
SomeViewController *onlyPortraitVC = [[SomeViewController alloc]init];

OnlyPortraitNavigationController *portraitNav = [[OnlyPortraitNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:onlyPortraitViewController];

[self presentViewController:portraitNav animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

this is work on my app hope it can help you.